# Unhandled Exception while sorting the elements in a linked list xstring

Tags: c++, sorting, exception, singly-linked-list, dynamic-variables

I'm working on a school project, and what I need to do is to sort the elements (strings) in a circular singly linked list alphabetically.

I thought that I could create a dynamic array and fill it with the elements from the list and send the elements back to the list after the array is sorted. It works great when I first ask the program to sort it. However, when I call the sort function again it gives an error. The error occurs on the line `temp[i] = head->info`. It shows me the xstring header file and says "unhandled exception".

I would be so happy if you can help me. I think what I'm missing here is a very basic thing, and I'll get better if I could learn what's wrong with this code. Thank you.

Edit:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
    private:
        T Name;
        T Surname;
        T Email;
        T PhoneNumber;
    public:
        Node();
        Node(T Name, T Surname, T Email, T PhoneNumber);
        Node(Node& copy);
        ~Node();
        T getName();
        T getSurname();
        T getEmail();
        T getPhoneNumber();
        void setName(T Name);
        void setSurname(T Surname);
        void setEmail(T Email);
        void setPhoneNumber(T PhoneNumber);
        Node<T>& operator= (const Node&);
};
```

This is the code for the function

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::sort()
{
    int sizeoflist = this->size();
    Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>[sizeoflist];
    for(int i=0; i<sizeoflist; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = head->info;
        this->removeFromHead();
    }

    //BUBBLE SORT
    for(int i=0; i<sizeoflist; i++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<sizeoflist -1 -i; k++)
        {
            if(temp[k].getSurname() > temp[k+1].getSurname())
            {
                Node<T> temp2 = temp[k];
                temp[k] = temp[k+1];
                temp[k+1] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }

    //FILLING THE LIST
    for(int i=0; i<sizeoflist; i++)
    {
        this->addToTail(temp[i]);
    }
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Assignment operator overloading code for the Node class.

```
template<class T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator= (const Node<T>& newNode)
{
    if(this == &newNode)
        return *this;
    Name = newNode.Name;
    Surname = newNode.Surname;
    Email = newNode.Email;
    PhoneNumber = newNode.PhoneNumber;
    return *this;
}
```

Edit:

I realized that there is something wrong with my addToTail function. It does add new elements to tail.

However, when I use addToHead instead of addToTail in my sort function it works perfectly after the first run too.

Here is my addToTail function

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::addToTail(Node<T> newInfo)
{
    LinkedList<T> *node = new LinkedList<T>;
    node->info = newInfo;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
        tail->next = head;
    }
    else
    {
        LinkedList<T> *temp = head;
        while(temp->next != head)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = node;
        node->next = head;
    }
}
```

And addToHead function

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::addToHead(Node<T> newinfo)
{
    LinkedList<T>* element = new LinkedList<T>;
    LinkedList<T>* temp = new LinkedList<T>;
    element->info = newinfo;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = element;
        tail = element;
        tail->next = head;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        head = element;
        head->next = temp;
        tail->next = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: They are private members of the class Node<T>. I tried to use set and get functions in case i'm doing something wrong here. But i got the same error afterwards.

Comment: Unhandled exception almost always means "using uninitialized or stale pointers". Since xstring is the implementation parts of `std::string` my guess would be that you are using a deleted or stale item in your list class.

Comment: By the way, your "Node" is a bit mixed up. I would have rather seen a `class`/`struct person_details` with the `name`, `phonenumber`, etc, and a `Node<person_details>`.

Comment: I checked the code for your suggestion I'm able to get the info from head->next->next->next->info.getName() even in my second run so i think i'm not using a deleted or stale item

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong jumps out in the code above.  The error may reside in `T`.  You mention an `xstring` in your subject line, but it doesn't appear in the body of your question.  What's that?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Notice there's no links or anything in there, so really wouldn't it just be `person_details`?  I don't see a need for a template here at all.

Comment: <string> includes it for the basic_string implementation. I only included <string>.

Comment: Yes there is no need for a template but somehow it's a bonus point for the project. I wasn't going to implement the classes like this. But it doesn't make anything bad so I used template to get a better grade.

Comment: Only other things I can think of:  Did `new` actually give you the array you asked for, or does it return `nullptr`?  Is `sizeOfList` the value you expect? (ie. if there's 10 items in there, does it return 10?)  Does `removeFromHead` correctly handle the case of a list becoming empty, so that `addToTail` does the right thing?  You should bring the code up in a debugger and make sure all your class invariants actually hold.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It turns out there is something wrong with my addToTail function but i can't understand what. I edited my question.

Comment: I checked it again. sizeOfList and new are working correctly.

Comment: I found what was wrong. I added "tail = node; tail->next = head;" under the else statement in the function addToTail and everything is working great now. Thank you for your time. It was my first question and I really liked the help I was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your `addToTail` function. You don't update the `tail` member variable to the new node. Also searching for the tail node using `while` is unnecessary because you have direct access to it via `tail`.

There also is an error in your `addToHead` function but it's not important here. You are allocating a new `temp` node which will always leak.

Perhaps fixing these errors is already enough. If it isn't you should show your `removeFromHead`. I guess it messes with the `head` variable and will leave it in some "uninitialized or stale" state, so that the next access to `head->next` crashes.

Comment: I couldn't up your answer because it requires 15 reputation. I updated the tail member and the errors are fixed. I also fixed the error in my addToHead function. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Volgaa you are welcome. BTW you could accept my answer by clicking the check mark below the up/down voting arrows.